# how to dynamically add a QWidget based to QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt4

I want to add a QWidget based class(composed by buttons and labels an so on...) to my QGraphicScene scene in a special position and respecting the graphic style of my scene.?

I am using QT 4.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use QGraphicsScene::addWidget() to add your widget to the scene and use the returned QGraphicsProxyWidget * to reposition your widget with QGraphicsItem::setPos().
Alternatively, you may look into QGraphicsWidget class.